# Closest or nearest value in two list in Python

Tags: python, list, closest

I have two lists

```
Calculated_list:  [[0.99, -9.58], [0.012, -9.88], [0.22, -9.56], [0.44, -6.6], 
                    [0.55, -7.7], [0.21, -6.6]]
Output_list:  [[0.20, -1.22], [0.22, -1.44], [0.1, -1.55], [0.43, -1.88], [0.34, 
                           1.9], [0.33, 0.2]]
```

I need  to compare and find the closest value of first value in each list of output list with the first value in each list of Calculated list.
For eg:
I need to compare 0.20 in [0.20,-1.22] with 0.99,0.012,0.22,0.44,0.55,0.21. and so on. If any closest value for 0.20 is in the list ie; 0.20 is closest to 0.21.
then take the second value in the corresponding list ie ; -6.6 ,then multiply  -6.6 in[0.21, -6.6] with -1.22 in [0.20, -1.22].

What I have tried:

```
for i in range(len(req_outlist)):
for j in range(len(reqlist)):
    #print(req_outlist[j])
    if (float(req_outlist[i][0])-float(reqlist[j][0]))==0:
        print(reqlist[j][0])

    else:
        print(" Closest Value")
```

Please help me with a code to achieve this.

Comment: Please write code to achieve this then we'll help fix it

Comment: Try to solve the problem yourself, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `(float(req_outlist[i][0])-float(reqlist[j][0]))==0` is unrealistic, it'll only find exact numeric matches (e.g. `0.20 - 0.20 == 0`). If you want to find the minimum of something, consider using the [`min()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) or using the `<` or `>` comparison operators somewhere in loops.

Comment: Have updated .Please help to fix this.

Comment: i need to find excatly the same or any closest value corresponding to a value in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
calculated_list = [[0.99, -9.58], [0.012, -9.88], [0.22, -9.56], [0.44, -6.6], 
    [0.55, -7.7], [0.21, -6.6]]
output_list = [[0.20, -1.22], [0.22, -1.44], [0.1, -1.55], [0.43, -1.88], [0.34, 1.9], 
    [0.33, 0.2]]

def FindClosest(input_list, input_point):
    output_value = min(map(lambda x: [abs(x[0] - input_point[0]), x[1]], input_list), key = lambda k: k[0])
    return [ input_point[0], input_point[1] * output_value[1] ]

result = list(map(lambda x: FindClosest(calculated_list, x), output_list))
print(result)
>>> [[0.2, 8.052], [0.22, 13.7664], [0.1, 15.314000000000002], [0.43, 12.408], [0.34, -12.54], [0.33, -1.32]]
```

Essentially, all this code does is run over the list and compare the difference between value you submitted, `input_point`, and the first item in the sublist at that index, to the current minimum difference. If it's less, the value is calculated and the minimum difference is updated. At the end, it's appended to `result`. Then we just do that for each item in the list.

Comment: I need to  find closest value for each 0.20,0.22 ,0.1, 0.43, 0.34,0.33 in the Output list

Comment: I need to find closest value for each first value in Output List

Comment: @bin123 Sorry, I was interrupted by my standup. Please take a look at the updated answer

Comment: NameError: name 'FindClosest' is not defined; error occurs

Comment: Hello I have got the result as [[0.2, -1.9120000000000001], [0.22, -2.1032], [0.1, -0.9880000000000001], [0.43, -2.8379999999999996], [0.34, -2.244], [0.33, -2.178]]. Can you please explain how -1.9120000000000001 occurs

Comment: For 0.22 is same in two list i need to get the second value as -1.44*-9.56 =13.7664 ie [0.22 13.7664] but what i get in the code as -2.1032. Please help

Comment: Please help to fix this

Comment: i need to find the nearest closest value for the list. Please help

Comment: @bn123 I see what you wanted now. Sorry, I clearly didn't fully understand what you were asking

Comment: It is saying an error: Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float' .

Comment: An error of Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'occurs Please help to fix this @Woody1193

Comment: @bin123 That is probably an error on your end. I can copy-paste this into a Python console session and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

To get to the right answer you need to use the value of input_list * value of output_list.

I made a slight change to Woody's answer (added the value as input_point2) and I think that is the result that met your requirement:

```
A =[[0.99, -9.58], [0.012, -9.88], [0.22, -9.56], [0.44, -6.6], \
                [0.55, -7.7], [0.21, -6.6]]

B =  [[0.20, -1.22], [0.22, -1.44], [0.1, -1.55], [0.43, -1.88], \
                [0.34, 1.9], [0.33, 0.2]]

def FindClosest(input_list, input_point1, input_point2):
    output_value = min(map(lambda x: [abs(x[0] - input_point1), x[1]], \
                           input_list), key = lambda k: k[0])    
    return [ input_point1, input_point2 * output_value[1] ]

result = list(map(lambda x: FindClosest(A, x[0], x[1]), B))

print(result)
```

Output:

[[0.2, 8.052], [0.22, 13.7664], [0.1, 15.314000000000002], [0.43, 12.408], [0.34, -12.54], [0.33, -1.32]]

Comment: ,It    is saying an error: Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: check both of your lists to see if there are mis-match data types. Using your original lists my code ran fine in Python 3.